# The polynomial $f (t) = t^7 + 10t^2 − 5$ has no roots in the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Prove that the polynomial $$f (t) = t^7 + 10t^2 − 5$$ has no roots in the field
$\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5)$.

Comment: do you mean cubic and quintic roots i.e. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]5,\sqrt[5]5)$?

Comment: @oldrinb sorry not good at English.. Yep it has been edited already.

Comment: For me this question does not seem to be natural... what is the background for this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5)$ and  $\mathbb Q( \sqrt[5] 5)$ have degrees $3$ and $5$ over  $\mathbb Q$.
Since $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime the extension  $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5)$ has degree $15$ over  $\mathbb Q$.

On the other hand, the polynomial $f(t)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein.
So if it had a root $a\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5)$, we would have $[\mathbb Q(a):\mathbb Q]=7$.
But then we would have (by the multiplicativity of degrees in towers of extensions)  $$15=[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5):\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5):\mathbb Q(a)] \cdot [\mathbb Q(a):\mathbb Q] = [\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5):\mathbb Q(a)] \cdot 7         $$  an impossibility.
So indeed no root $a$ of $f(t)$ can exist in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5)$ .

Comment: @user: 1) You claim without any argument that this a homework question and your 99% figure is drawn from thin air.2) If the OP appreciates my answer so much the better: I wanted to help **him** and not bow to your criteria for a good answer. 3) What I said suffices to prove that the extension has degree *exactly* $15$ to anyone who has a minimal understanding of elementary field theory. It is rather ironical that you reproach me both for  giving "a too extended answer" and then for not giving a full proof of an essentially trivial result!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1.** Find the degree of field extension $\mathbb Q\subset\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3] 5, \sqrt[5] 5)$.

**Hint 2.** Prove that $f (t) = t^7 + 10t^2 − 5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.